# Symfony2 forms and <input> pattern attribute

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to create a form in Symfony2 with a text input field that accepts a string consisting of 6 digits followed by a dash followed by four digits (e.g. 123456-7890). It does work, but I'm getting inconsistent HTML markup depending on exactly how I add the field to the form.

This is from the entity:

```
class Kursist
{
...
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=11)
 */
protected $cpr;
....
public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
{
    $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('cpr', new NotBlank());
    $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('cpr', new Regex(array(
        'pattern' => '/^\d{6}-\d{4}$/',
    )));
}
```

From the form definition:

```
class KursistType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder->add('cpr');
    ...
  }
}
```

From the twig template:

```
<form action= ... >;
  {{ form_row(form.cpr) }}
    ...
</form>
```

This is what the browser source code looks like - note the *pattern* and *maxlength* attributes:

```
<label for="KursistType_cpr" class="required">Cpr</label><input type="text" id="KursistType_cpr" name="KursistType[cpr]" required="required" maxlength="11" pattern="\d{6}-\d{4}" value="123456-7890" />
```

I want to use my own label rather than the default, so I change the form field defition:

```
    class KursistType extends AbstractType
    {
      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
      {
        $builder->add('cpr','text', array('label' => 'CPR'));
        ...
```

But now when I look at the browser source code, the *pattern* and *maxlength* attributes have gone:

```
    <label for="KursistType_cpr" class="required">CPR</label><input type="text" id="KursistType_cpr" name="KursistType[cpr]" required="required" value="123456-7890" />
```

Is there some way to modify the label using the FormBuilderInterface without these attributes being dropped?

Comment: I looks like a Symfony2 bug, it should work normally...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This inconsistency is due to [type options guessing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#field-type-options-guessing) which happens in first case when you dont provide any additional information about field to form builder.

When option guessing is disabled, you can provide field attributes explicitly.

```
$builder->add('cpr','text', array('label' => 'CPR', 'pattern' => '\d{6}-\d{4}'));
```

Or even you can keep option guessing enabled, but override only label attribute

```
$builder->add('cpr',null, array('label' => 'CPR'));
```